# Is there possibity to migrate data from Old Solace VMR to latest Solace pubsub+ version?

Tags: solace

Is there possibity to migrate data(topic, queues and all other config) from Old Solace VMR to latest Solace pubsub+ version?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading your VMR to the latest Solace PubSub+ software message broker will preserve all data including messages that are spooled.

If upgrading is not an option, you can capture all message-vpn level data (including topics and queues) with the "show current-config message-vpn *" command. You can use the “>” and “>>” characters to redirect the output to a file and run this file as a script on the new Solace PubSub+ software message broker.

The output is generally backwards compatible but keep in mind that it may not be possible to take the configuration from a newer version of the Solace message broker and apply it on an older version as there may have been new features and commands added.